# Access base class protected members using pointers to base class in derived class

Tags: c++, protected, access-rights

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::endl;
using std::cout;

template<typename T>
class B{
protected:
    T value;
    B* ptr;
public:
    B(T t):value(t), ptr(0){}
};

template<typename T>
class D: public B<T>{
public:
    void f();
    D(T t):B<T>(t){}
};

template<typename T>
void D<T>::f(){
    cout << this->value << endl;     //OK!
    this->ptr = this;
    cout << this->ptr->value << endl;      //error! cannot access protected member!!
    B<T>* a = this;
    cout << a->value <<endl;       //error! cannot access protected member!!
}


int main(){
    D<double> a(1.2);
    a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the member of the base class can be directly accessed using `this` pointer, but not the other pointers.
Does the compiler consider them as different instantiation?

Comment: What has this to do with templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. [Protected members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Protected_member_access) of base class can be accessed in the derived class, but only via an object of a type that *is* the derived class (or the further derived class of current derived class) (including `this`). That means you can't access protected members via a pointer to base class.

> A protected member of a class Base can only be accessed
>
> 1) ...
>
> 2) by the members of any class derived from Base, but only when
>   operating on an object of a type that is derived from Base (including
>   this)

Comment: Your description isn't exactly the same - the quote suggests it can be accessed from a member of one derived class when operating on an object of a *different* derived class, too.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @TobySpeight Answer revised. About different derived class, further derived class is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler test example:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int i;
};

class D1 : public Base
{
};

class D2 : public Base
{
    int a(Base& b) { return b.i; } // error
    int a(D1& d) { return d.i; }   // error

    int a(D2& d) { return d.i; }
};
```

In the derived class `D2`, we can access `Base::i` in a `D2` instance, but not in a `Base` instance, nor in an object that derives from `Base` not through `D2`.

The otherwise-good [C++ Reference][protected] says:

> A protected member of a class `Base` can be accessed [...] by the members of any class derived from `Base`, but only when operating on an object of a type that is derived from `Base` (including `this`).

The test above suggests that the wording is slightly inaccurate there¹ - it should read "only when operating on an object of its own type or one derived from it".

---

¹ or that GCC is incorrect - we should really check the standard for this.